# Show query result differently

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT pr_products.product AS PRODUCT, pr_varieties.variety AS VARIETY, pr_grades.GRADE, SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS QUANTITY
FROM pf_harvest
INNER JOIN pf_performance ON pf_performance.id = pf_harvest.id_performance
INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = pf_harvest.id_variety
INNER JOIN pr_grades ON pr_grades.id = pf_harvest.id_grade
WHERE pf_performance.status = 100
AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
AND pf_harvest.date = '2017-03-22'
GROUP BY pf_harvest.id_product, pf_harvest.id_variety, pf_harvest.id_grade
ORDER BY pf_harvest.id_product, pr_varieties.variety, pf_harvest.id_grade;
```

Which shows me the following result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   PRODUCT     |     VARIETY     |     GRADE      |     QUANTITY  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE        |     ROSEV1      |     GRADE1     |     1000      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE        |     ROSEV1      |     GRADE2     |     5000      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE        |     ROSEV2      |     GRADE1     |     2000      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE1       |     ROSE1V1     |     GRADE1     |     3500      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to display the query result as follows?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  PRODUCT     |   VARIETY   |  GRADE1  |  GRADE2 |  TOTAL         |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE       |   ROSEV1    |  1000    |  5000   |  6000          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE       |   ROSEV2    |  2000    |    0    |  2000          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROSE1      |   ROSE1V1   |  3500    |    0    |  3500          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to change the query but I could not and I would like to know if it is possible, I hope someone can help me.

**UPDATED**
NOTE: There may be more GRADES in the query result (GRADE1, GRADE2, GRADE3...).

Thanks!

Comment: Pivoting in SQL is one of the most common questions across all RDBMS's, no doubt in the hundreds on SO! Look up *conditional aggregation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your current query by not grouping on the `GRADE` column, but instead pivot on that column.  Then, use conditional aggregation to compute the `GRADE1` and `GRADE2` columns.

```
SELECT t3.product AS PRODUCT,
       t4.variety AS VARIETY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t5.GRADE = 'GRADE1' THEN t1.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS GRADE1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t5.GRADE = 'GRADE2' THEN t1.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS GRADE2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t5.GRADE = 'GRADE3' THEN t1.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS GRADE3,
       -- hopefully it is clear how to add more grades
       SUM(t1.quantity) AS TOTAL
FROM pf_harvest t1
INNER JOIN pf_performance t2 
    ON t2.id = t1.id_performance
INNER JOIN pr_products t3
    ON t3.id = pf_harvest.id_product
INNER JOIN pr_varieties t4
    ON t4.id = t1.id_variety
INNER JOIN pr_grades t5
    ON t5.id = t1.id_grade
WHERE t2.status = 100 AND
      t1.id_tenant = 1 AND
      t1.date = '2017-03-22'
GROUP BY t1.id_product,
         t1.id_variety
ORDER BY t1.id_product,
         t4.variety,
         t1.id_grade;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but There may be more GRADES in the query result (GRADE1, GRADE2, GRADE3...)

Comment: Then you are going to need dynamic SQL for that.  There is no quick and dirty solution.

Comment: more fun! let's flag this incomplete issue shall we?

Comment: How many more *Grades*? If manageable, say ten then repeat those conditional aggregates. And since this is more a reporting than data storage need, import query into an application layer code. @TimBiegeleisen can help you with an R solution which can easily connect to MySQL and reshape data long to wide!

Comment: No, it's less than 10 @Parfait

Answer (score 0):

try this

added this code

```
sum(case when pr_grades.Grade='Grade1' then pf_harvest.quantity else 0 end)) [Grade1],
      sum(case when pr_grades.Grade='Grade2' then pf_harvest.quantity else 0 end)) [Grade2]
```

---

```
SELECT
  pr_products.product AS PRODUCT,
  pr_varieties.variety AS VARIETY,
  sum(case when pr_grades.Grade='Grade1' then pf_harvest.quantity else 0 end)) [Grade1],
  sum(case when pr_grades.Grade='Grade2' then pf_harvest.quantity else 0 end)) [Grade2],
  SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS TOTAL
FROM pf_harvest
INNER JOIN pf_performance
  ON pf_performance.id = pf_harvest.id_performance
INNER JOIN pr_products
  ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
INNER JOIN pr_varieties
  ON pr_varieties.id = pf_harvest.id_variety
INNER JOIN pr_grades
  ON pr_grades.id = pf_harvest.id_grade
WHERE pf_performance.status = 100
AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
AND pf_harvest.date = '2017-03-22'
GROUP BY pf_harvest.id_product,
         pf_harvest.id_variety
ORDER BY pf_harvest.id_product, pr_varieties.variety, pf_harvest.id_grade;
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Nice copy of my answer.

Comment: did not copy your answer.. i just corrected a number of clerical issues when i reviewed the problem. FYI answered 11mins ago.. you just answered  6 mins ago.